# Trouble understanding discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform, dft

In the paper [Calculation of a constant Q spectral transform - J.C.Brown](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Brown91-cqt.pdf) it is mentioned

> The conventional linear frequency representation given by the discrete Fourier transform gives rise to a constant separation between components for musical sounds consisting of harmonic components

Since DFT requires the samples to be [equally separated](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~sjrob/Teaching/SP/l7.pdf) how would we always get constant separation between the frequencies ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Ms. Brown is referring to the notion shown in the figure below.  The top panel shows the spectral magnitude of a sawtooth sequence, that repeats five times per second (fundamental freq = 5 Hz), with a linear DFT freq axis. Notice the "constant separation between harmonic components."  The figure's bottom panel shows the same spec magnitude with a logarithmic freq axis. There the frequency separation between harmonic components is *not* constant.

[image]